# Determining Linear Independence/Dependence & non-trivial solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

I put the vectors in a matrix and reduced it, solved the determinant and got 0. This tells me that the vectors are linearly dependent. I am not sure how to figure out the non-trivial relation. This is my reduced matrix.

---

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0&-1/4 \\ 
 0&  1& 1\\ 
 0&  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

$$
A = \left\{\begin{matrix}
-60\\ 
-4\\ 
-72
\end{matrix}\right.
:
B = \left\{\begin{matrix}
-5\\ 
-1\\ 
-5
\end{matrix}\right.
:
C = \left\{\begin{matrix}
10\\ 
0\\ 
13
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

__A +*_*_*B +*___C  = 0

Find coefficients.

Comment: Your reduced matrix corresponds to the system of equations, $a+b-(1/4)c=0,b+c=0$. Find a non-zero solution to that system. That solution will be the coefficients in the relation.

Comment: Since they're dependent, can I set A = 1?

Comment: Also, shouldn't your equation just read a - (1/4)c?

Comment: How can you set $A=1$, when $A=\pmatrix{-60\cr-4\cr-72\cr}$? Or do you mean $a$ when you write $A$? In that case, set $a=1$, and see what happens.

Comment: My 1st equation comes from the first row. The first row is $(1,1,-1/4)$. So, my 1st equation is $a+b-(1/4)c=0$.

Comment: I don't mean vector A, more so x1 or x1 when solving the system. I set a to 1 and solved a - (1/4)c and got the right answer.

Comment: Sorry, the rref was written down incorrectly on my post. Should be 1 0 -1/4

Comment: OK, now that you knopw how to do the problem, please write it up and post it as an answer. Then, later, you can accept your answer. Helps clear up the Unanswered Questions list.

Comment: And by setting a to 1, I think it may be better to set the free variable to 1 and solve the system, since it's dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Found the RREF, set the free variable to 1, since it's linearly dependent and solved the system of equations to get coefficients.